# Conditionally setting colour of a bound element in XAML based on another field of datasource

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

I have the following item template in a WP7 listbox. My bound type has a boolean property (Status) and I would like to conditionally set the colour of the site name based on this. How would I go about doing this please?

Thanks in advance!

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
  <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432">
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding SiteName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Url}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" />
  </StackPanel>
 </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with a converter. Either you can have the converter return a color, or you can have two TextBlocks each with the color you want, and use a Boolean to Visibility, and one that is a reverse visibility, converters to hide/show each of the controls.

One word of caution is that converters can be slow, so sometimes it's more performant to bind to a ViewModel and on that ViewModel provide the convetered values that you need.